# Winrar repair corrupted .Rar Files

Tags: rar

Good day, I have not extracted .rar file. I go to open it and get the error message An error has occurred while while expanding the file '*.rar' Format error. Any Help?

Comment: Why the heck you weren't able to migrate this to superuser???

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `.rar` file that you're trying to open is corrupted.